# unexpected output and return value with Cython

Tags: python, python-2.7, cython

First, I'm using Cython 0.18 with Python 2.7.4. I'm experiencing a rather strange bug, and I'm not sure why. Here's the toy code:

```
from cpython cimport bool

cpdef unsigned int func(char *seq1, char *seq2, bool case_sensitive=True):
        print 'seq1', seq1, len(seq1)
        print 'seq2', seq2, len(seq2)
        print

        #take care of case sensitivity
        if not case_sensitive:
                #this is kinda hacky, but I've gotta assign the lowercased string to a Python object before assigning it back to char *
                #see http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/language_basics.html#caveats-when-using-a-python-string-in-a-c-context
                temp = seq1.lower()
                seq1 = temp

                temp = seq2.lower()
                seq2 = temp

        print 'seq1', seq1, len(seq1)
        print 'seq2', seq2, len(seq2)
        print

        #trim common characters at the beginning of the words
        while len(seq1) > 0 and len(seq2) > 0 and seq1[0] == seq2[0]:
                temp = seq1[1:]
                seq1 = temp

                temp = seq2[1:]
                seq2 = temp

        print 'seq1', seq1, len(seq1)
        print 'seq2', seq2, len(seq2)
        print

        #handle degenerate cases
        if not seq1:
                return len(seq2)
        if not seq2:
                return len(seq1)
```

Here's a sample call:

```
>>> from func import func
>>> print func('TUESDAYs', 'tuesday', False)
```

Now, what I expect to see if the following:

```
seq1 TUESDAYs 8
seq2 tuesday 7

seq1 tuesdays 8
seq2 tuesday 7

seq1 s 1
seq2  0

1
```

But what I actually see is this:

```
seq1 TUESDAYs 8
seq2 tuesday 7

seq1 tuesdays 8
seq2 tuesday 7

seq1 stdout 6
seq2 tuesday 7

0
```

What the hell is going on here? First of all, why is `stdout` outputting at all? Why aren't I getting the output I should be getting? Is this a Cython bug, or am I just missing something trivial here?

Comment: I notice that you're using `seq1` and `seq2` as `str` objects right from the start, and I'll bet if you add an explicit conversion (change the params to `s1` and `s2`, then write `str1, str2 = str(s1), str(s2)` at the top), the problem goes away. (At least it's worth testing.)

Comment: It's a workaround necessary for interacting with ``char *`` and Python ``str`` objects. I have a comment in the code that describes why I do that. Your idea of casting seq1 and seq2 to str is an interesting one. I'll try it. Be right back....

Comment: Yeah, I figured that part out and deleted the comment. But that's what inspired the second comment. You're not getting any performance benefits out of using a char* internally—in fact, I think you're making it slower. For each intermediate step, you create a Python `str` object, do `str` operations, store the `str` results, then make `seq1` point at that `str`'s buffer. And then you build a new `str` out of `seq1`, when you could have just ref'd the old one if you hadn't tricked Cython.

Comment: Actually… that's where the problem comes from, too. As the docs you linked to say, "It is then your responsibility to hold the reference p for as long as possible." Let me write up an answer.

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely right! That was a really easy fix. I'll mark your answer as accepted once it appears. Thanks!

Comment: With Apple Python 2.7.2 and Cython 0.17.1, I got exactly the same output, at least on my first run. I expected the same kind of garbage, of course, but not the exact _same_ garbage. I started looking through the generated C code to try to figure out exactly why, but… it's not worth it. And with three different Python 3.x versions, I consistently get `b'tuesday'` as the string (or, rather, as the `bytes`, so it prints as `seq1 b"b'tuesday'" 10`) instead of `stdout`… Go figure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is in all of the cases like this:

```
temp = seq1.lower()
seq1 = temp

temp = seq2.lower()
```

The reason you need to do this dance instead of just `seq1 = seq1.lower()`—as you pointed out in your question—is because of [Caveats when using a Python string in a C context](http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/language_basics.html#caveats-when-using-a-python-string-in-a-c-context).

But what you're doing isn't correct, it's just good enough to trick Cython into *thinking* it's correct, and compiling garbage.

Let's step through line by line:

```
temp = seq1.lower()
```

This creates a `str` out of `seq1`, calls its `lower()`, and stores the result in `temp`.

```
seq1 = temp
```

This makes `seq1` into a pointer to the internal buffer of the `str` object in `temp`. As the docs specifically say:

> It is then your responsibility to hold the reference p for as long as necessary.

```
temp = seq2.lower()
```

This yadda-yadda-yaddas, and stores the result in `temp`. As a consequence, it frees the old value of `temp`. Which was the only reference that you had to that `str`. So, the GC is free to collect it, and does so immediately. Which means `seq1` is now pointing at the internal buffer of a freed object.

The first two times, you apparently get lucky, and that buffer doesn't get reused. But eventually, in the `while` loop, it fails, the buffer gets reused, and you end up with a pointer to some other string buffer.

---

So, how do you solve this?

Well, you could keep all those intermediate references around as long as they're needed.

But really, why do you need `seq1` and `seq2` to be `char*` values anyway? You're not getting any performance benefit out of it. In fact, you're getting an extra performance *cost* out of it. Every time you use `seq1` as a `str`, it's creating a new `str` object out of that buffer (and copying the buffer), even though you already had a perfectly good one that you could have just retained instead, if you hadn't tricked Cython.

So, the easiest fix is to replace the first line with:

```
cpdef unsigned int func(char *sequence1, char *sequence2, bool case_sensitive=True):
    seq1, seq2 = str(sequence1), str(sequence2)
```

(You don't really need the `str` calls there; the fact that you didn't `cdef` the variables should be enough. But I think this makes the intention clearer.)